# Why is there no single player in "looking to play" section in CSGO and every time I solo queue I get matched up with new accounts without any medals?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

This has been happening for the last few days. I don’t know if it's because of the new update or what, but I can barely see any players in the "looking to play" section. There are only a few people. Usually there are a lot of players from the neighboring countries and from similar ranks to mine. MY internet connection is okay; I didn’t even get high ping. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Has your account been banned in any way?